# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, webview

Hola tengo un error en mi proyecto de Xcode.
Estoy intentando integrar la lógica del WebView a si que integre el siguiente código:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var reser: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var produ: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rp: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var anali: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var web: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var du: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginu: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var logoutu: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let reserr = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        let reserrr = URLRequest(url: reserr!)
        reser.load(reserrr)

        let produr = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        let produrr = URLRequest(url: produr!)
        produ.load(produrr)

        let rpr = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        let rprr = URLRequest(url: rpr!)
        rp.load(rprr)

        let analir = URL(string: https://google.com")
        let analirr = URLRequest(url: analir!)
        anali.load(analirr)

        let webr = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        let webrr = URLRequest(url: webr!)
        web.load(webrr)

        let dur = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        let durr = URLRequest(url: dur!)
        du.load(durr)

        let loginur = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        let loginurr = URLRequest(url: loginur!)
        loginu.load(loginurr)

        let logoutur = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        let logouturr = URLRequest(url: logoutur!)
        logoutu.load(logouturr)

    }


}
```

En la linea donde pone: `reser.load(reserrr)` Xcode me da el siguiente error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

¿Cual es la solución a este problema?

Entorno:
Xcode 9 pero el proyecto fue creado con Xcode 10 Beta

Swift 4

Answer (score 0):

¿Sabes que son los valores opcionales? El tipo URL es opcional, ya que es una dirección a un archivo que puede o no existir. En el caso de que no exista o no se encuentre devolverá *nil*, es decir valor nulo. Por eso llamas a reserr con una exclamación, para desempaquetar el valor de la variable. Pero esto sólo se debe hacer (en general) si se está seguro de que el valor de la variable no es nulo.
Si el programa desempaqueta la variable y se encuentra “sin nada” lanza error porque esperaba un valor que le has asegurado que estaría ahí.

¿Has probado a cambiar el código para ver qué falla, reser o reserr?

Comment: Hola Gracias por tu respuesta @Rube, he probado ha poner en comentario `reser.load(reserrr)` que es lo que me ponía que fallaba y el proyecto ha arrancado sin problemas entonces creo que el error viene de  `reser.load(reserrr)`

Comment: Creo que no has entendido bien. Lo que decía era que añadieras código para ver qué da el error, si reser o reserr. Es decir, cuál de los dos provoca el fallo. ¿Has probado a revisar el @IBOutlet? Es posible que ahí esté el fallo. Bórralo y vuélvelo a crear.

Comment: Si lo he borrado y lo he vuelto a poner y el @IBOutlet no da el error

Comment: Pues si no es el IBOutlet, será problema de reser. Prueba a eliminar completamente el elemento de la vista en el storyboard y vuelve a crearlo. No veo ningún error en el código.